# should I stop geth for copying /chaindata to another machine?

Tags: go-ethereum, chaindata

Since I've made stats from geth full node by calling rpc api, it is burdensome for me to stop geth a few hours.

Nowadays my local machine uses about 95% disk, so I want to migrate my /chaindata to another machine.

But after I copied original /chaindata to another machine while running original geth, running new full geth on another machine failed with error message.

`Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: gap (#8952595) in the chain between ancients and leveldb`

What I have to do?
Should I have to stop geth and copy /chaindata?

Answer (score 1):

Of course. It should be stopped.